# Customize the addlink in Admin changelist, by conditions passed through querystring

Tags: django, django-admin, django-templates

I change the admin view like described in:
[How Do I Show Django Admin Change List View of foreign key children?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662359/how-do-i-show-django-admin-change-list-view-of-foreign-key-children)

I have Customer -> Project -> Action
I get all actions for a project by this method:

```
def related_actions(self, obj):
    from django.core import urlresolvers
    url = urlresolvers.reverse("admin:workflow_action_changelist")
    lookup = u"project__exact"
    text = obj.name
    return u"<a href='%s?%s=%d'>%s</a>" % (url, lookup, obj.pk, text)
```

Now i want to customize the addlink in the change_list. The admin change_list is overwritten by a template in /workflow/templates/admin/workflow/action/change_list.html
But all three models use the same template.
So i think there must be a better solution as harcode param in the template
When i change the line

```
<a href="add/{% if is_popup %}?_popup=1{% endif %}" class="addlink">
```

to

```
<a href="add/?actionstatus=5" class="addlink">
```

the actioncategory is preselected in the new action form. But how could i override the addlink in each model.

I must get the actionstatus by the param in the projectsview:

```
/workflow/action/?project__exact=5
```

Any suggestions?

Is there something like this pseudo for use in action model ?

```
 def add(self)
     get param projectid from url 
     return "<a href='/workflow/action/add/%s' target='_blank'>Add Action</a>" % (parent.project id)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, no such `add`.
You could customize the **change_list.html**, especially its the *object-list-item* block by extending:

```
{% block object-tools-items %}
  <li>
    <a href="{% url cl.opts|admin_urlname:'add' %}{% if is_popup %}?_popup=1{% else %}?{% endif %}{% if "project" in cl.params %}&amp;project={{ cl.params.project }}{% endif %}" class="addlink">
      {% blocktrans with cl.opts.verbose_name as name %}Add {{ name }}{% endblocktrans %}
    </a>
  </li> 
{% endblock %}
```

Here, `cl` is the `ChangeList` instance. `cl.params` is filtered `request.GET`. The code checks whether there is `project` in querystring and appends its value to the generated addlink.

You could also write JS code to update add link when changelist page finishs loading. something like

```
(function($){
$(function(){
var m = window.location.search.match(/[?&]project=([^&]*)/);
if (m){
    var link = $('a.addlink').attr('href');
    $('a.addlink').attr('href', link+(link.match(/\?_popup=1$/)?'&':'?')+'project='+m[1]);
}
});
})(django.jQuery);
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090948/change-url-parameters-with-jquery) for general params manipulation.

Comment: Thanks, with this i can add the GET params for every model. It works fine. Parent ForeignKey (Selectbox) is preselected. ;-)

Comment: Can you give me an advice or example JS which updates the add link? I prefer the first solution. Just for interest. Thanks.