# How to nest child models in Django Admin page or add a link between them?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a book object which needs to be categorized up to sub 5 categories. The business requirement required the admin to add these categories page by page by first adding first-level categories and then click on each on to add second-level categories, After that, click on each one to add the third-level and so on up to 5. the below figure can describe the idea.

Django inlines can add two objects of different models on the same page Which can help me only for the second-level categories, but what if I want to click in that second object to add subs inside it?

Is that possible in Django? from the DB side, I think one table with the following attributes: key, value, and parent can help me in storing all the categories and whenever I wanted them on the client side I can arrange them before sending them in views. But the issue is on the admin side, how can I do it in that way?

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `nested_admin` might help.
Please, check out the reference.
https://django-nested-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Comment: yes, thanks! also, these may help 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662359/how-do-i-show-django-admin-change-list-view-of-foreign-key-children 

https://djangopy.org/how-to/how-to-implement-categories-in-django/